# How to JUnit test that two List<E> contain the same elements in the same order?

Tags: java, junit, guava

### Context

I am writing a simple **[JUnit](http://www.junit.org/)** test for the `MyObject` class.

A `MyObject` can be created from a static factory method that takes a varargs of **[String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)**.

```
MyObject.ofComponents("Uno", "Dos", "Tres");
```

At any time during the existence of `MyObject`, clients can inspect the parameters it was created by in the form of a **[List<E>](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html)**, through the `.getComponents()` method.

```
myObject.ofComponents(); // -> List<String>: { "Uno", "Dos", "Tres" }
```

In other words, a `MyObject` both remembers and exposes the list of parameters that brought it into existence. More details about this contract:

- The order of `getComponents` will be the same as the one chosen for object creation
- Duplicate subsequent **[String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)** components are allowed and retained in order
- Behaviour on `null` is undefined (other code guarantees no `null` gets to the factory)
- There are no ways to alter the list of components after object instantiation

I am writing a simple test that creates a `MyObject` from a list of **[String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)** and checks that it can return the same list via `.getComponents()`. *I do this immediately but this is supposed to happen at a distance in a realistic code path*.

### Code

Here my attempt:

---

```
List<String> argumentComponents = Lists.newArrayList("One", "Two", "Three");
List<String> returnedComponents =
    MyObject.ofComponents(
        argumentComponents.toArray(new String[argumentComponents.size()]))
        .getComponents();
assertTrue(Iterables.elementsEqual(argumentComponents, returnedComponents));
```

---

### Question

- Is **[Google Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/)** `Iterables.elementsEqual()` the best way, provided I have the library in my build path, to compare those two lists? *this is something I have been agonizing about; should I use this helper method which goes over an [Iterable<E>](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html).. check size and then iterate running `.equals()`.. or any other of the methods that an Internet search suggests? what's the canonical way to compare lists for unit tests?*

#### Optional insights I would love to get

- Is the method test designed reasonably? I am not an expert in **[JUnit](http://www.junit.org/)**!
- Is `.toArray()` the best way to convert a **[List<E>](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html)** to a varargs of E?

Comment: +1 for well structured question.

Comment: Hamcrest has `IsIterableContainingInOrder` which is designed exactly for testing as opposed to `Iterables`. Using Hamcrest will give good messages in case of failure.

Comment: [fest-assert](https://github.com/alexruiz/fest-assert-2.x/wiki) provides an elegant fluent api...

Comment: @JohnB: Hamcrest is great and ideal for testing, which is what I was asking (thx!), but in this particular case `IsIterableContainingInOrder` is not strict enough, right? `M={A,B,C}` contains `N={A,B}` in order but `M!=N`.

Comment: @Robottinosino According to the javadoc `Creates a matcher for Iterables that matches when a single pass over the examined Iterable yields a series of items, each logically equal to the corresponding item in the specified items. For a positive match, the examined iterable must be of the same length as the number of specified items`

Comment: This means (and I have used it as such) the two lists must be of the same size and each element must match. I know the name suggests that it is a weaker test but it is what you are looking for. You could always confirm by writing a quick test passing in the lists from your comment

Answer (score 66, accepted):

I prefer using Hamcrest because it gives much better output in case of a failure

```
Assert.assertThat(listUnderTest, 
       IsIterableContainingInOrder.contains(expectedList.toArray()));
```

Instead of reporting

`expected true, got false`

it will report

`expected List containing "1, 2, 3, ..." got list containing "4, 6, 2, ..."`

[IsIterableContainingInOrder.contain](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/collection/IsIterableContainingInOrder.html#contains%28E...%29)

[Hamcrest](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/)

According to the Javadoc:

> Creates a matcher for Iterables that matches when a single pass over the examined Iterable yields a series of items, each logically equal to the corresponding item in the specified items. For a positive match, the examined iterable must be of the same length as the number of specified items

So the `listUnderTest` must have the same number of elements and each element must match the expected values in order.

Comment: IsIterableContainingInOrder is not strict enough for equality checking?

Comment: what do you mean / what are you asking?

Comment: The output is the same for Hamcrest as for normal jUnit assertions.

assertEquals(expected, actual); will output:

java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<[1, 2]> but was:<[3, 4]>

I dont think Hamcrest has any benefits in the means of the output

Comment: @henrik - Actually output from Hamcrest is `Expected: iterable containing [<1>, <3>, <5>, <7>] but: item 3: was <6>`. In a long list of elements whose `toString` output may be quite long, knowing which element is incorrect can be quite helpful.

Comment: @JohnB in that scenario, I agree

Comment: `IsIterableContainingInOrder.contain()` is misleading name. It doesn't reflect the fact that it additionally validates whether `actual` has same number of elements (size equality check). `hasSameElementsAs()` would be more appropriate name

Answer (score 87):

Why not simply use `List#equals`?

```
assertEquals(argumentComponents, imapPathComponents);
```

[Contract of `List#equals`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29):

> two lists are defined to be equal if they contain the same elements in the same order.

Comment: Which particular matcher from Hamcrest? I could use precise assertion failure messages provided for free...

Comment: Like for using no external libraries

Comment: IMHO this code looks much clearer than Hamcrest's `IsIterableContainingInOrder.contain()` (which name don't fully reflect its behaviour). So if you have collections other than List<> then it's better to convert them to the List and use this code rather than to array which is required by Hamcrest.

Comment: Just noting that it needs `import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;` import

Answer (score 12):

The equals() method on your List implementation should do elementwise comparison, so

```
assertEquals(argumentComponents, returnedComponents);
```

is a lot easier.

Answer (score 11):

`org.junit.Assert.assertEquals()` and `org.junit.Assert.assertArrayEquals()` do the job.

To avoid next questions: If you want to ignore the order put all elements to set and then compare: `Assert.assertEquals(new HashSet<String>(one), new HashSet<String>(two))`

If however you just want to ignore duplicates but preserve the order wrap you list with `LinkedHashSet`.

Yet another tip.  The trick `Assert.assertEquals(new HashSet<String>(one), new HashSet<String>(two))` works fine until the comparison fails. In this case it shows you error message with to  string representations of your sets that can be confusing because the order in set is almost not predictable (at least for complex objects). So, the trick I found is to wrap the collection with sorted set instead of `HashSet`. You can use `TreeSet` with custom comparator.

Comment: Using an HashSet will not preserve the order and *the duplicates*.

Answer (score 6):

**assertTrue()/assertFalse() : to use only to assert boolean result returned**

> assertTrue(Iterables.elementsEqual(argumentComponents,
>   returnedComponents));

You want to use `Assert.assertTrue()` or `Assert.assertFalse()` as the method under test returns a `boolean` value.
As the method returns a specific thing such as a `List` that should contain some expected elements, asserting with `assertTrue()` in this way : `Assert.assertTrue(myActualList.containsAll(myExpectedList)`
 is an anti pattern.
It makes the assertion easy to write but as the test fails, it also makes it hard to debug because the test runner will only say to you something like :

> expected `true` but actual is `false`

**`Assert.assertEquals(Object, Object)` in JUnit4 or `Assertions.assertIterableEquals(Iterable, Iterable)` in JUnit 5 : to use only as both `equals()` and `toString()` are overrided for the classes (and deeply) of the compared objects**

It matters because the equality test in the assertion relies on `equals()` and the test failure message relies on `toString()` of the compared objects.
As `String` overrides both `equals()` and `toString()`, it is perfectly valid to assert the `List<String>` with  `assertEquals(Object,Object)`.
And about this matter : you have to override `equals()` in a class because it makes sense in terms of object equality, not only to make assertions easier in a test with JUnit.
To make assertions easier you have other ways (that you can see in the next points of the answer).

**Is Guava a way to perform/build unit test assertions ?**

> Is Google Guava Iterables.elementsEqual() the best way, provided I have the library in my build path, to compare those two lists?

No it is not. Guava is not an library to write unit test assertions.
You don't need it to write most (all I think) of unit tests.

**What's the canonical way to compare lists for unit tests?**

As a good practice I favor assertion/matcher libraries.

I cannot encourage JUnit to perform specific assertions because this provides really too few and limited features : it performs only an assertion with a deep equals.
Sometimes you want to allow any order in the elements, sometimes you want to allow that any elements of the expected match with the actual, and so for...

So using a unit test assertion/matcher library such as Hamcrest or AssertJ is the correct way.
The actual answer provides a Hamcrest solution. Here is a [AssertJ](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/) solution.

[`org.assertj.core.api.ListAssert.containsExactly()`](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/core-8/api/org/assertj/core/api/ListAssert.html#containsExactly-ELEMENT...-) is what you need : it verifies that the actual group contains exactly the given values and nothing else, in order as stated :

> Verifies that the actual group contains exactly the given values and
>   nothing else, in order.

Your test could look like :

```
import org.assertj.core.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

@Test
void ofComponent_AssertJ() throws Exception {
   MyObject myObject = MyObject.ofComponents("One", "Two", "Three");
   Assertions.assertThat(myObject.getComponents())
             .containsExactly("One", "Two", "Three");
}
```

A AssertJ  good point is that declaring a `List` as expected is needless : it makes the assertion straighter and the code more readable :

```
Assertions.assertThat(myObject.getComponents())
         .containsExactly("One", "Two", "Three");
```

And if the test fails  :

```
// Fail : Three was not expected 
Assertions.assertThat(myObject.getComponents())
          .containsExactly("One", "Two");
```

you get a very clear message such as :

> java.lang.AssertionError:
>
> Expecting:
>
> <["One", "Two", "Three"]>
>
> to contain exactly (and in same order):
>
> <["One", "Two"]>
>
> but some elements were not expected:
>
> <["Three"]>

**Assertion/matcher libraries are a must because these will really further**

Suppose that `MyObject` doesn't store `String`s but `Foo`s instances such as :

```
public class MyFooObject {

    private List<Foo> values;
    @SafeVarargs
    public static MyFooObject ofComponents(Foo... values) {
        // ...
    }

    public List<Foo> getComponents(){
        return new ArrayList<>(values);
    }
}
```

That is a very common need. 
With AssertJ the assertion is still simple to write. Better you can assert that the list content are equal even if the class of the elements doesn't override `equals()/hashCode()` while JUnit ways require that :

```
import org.assertj.core.api.Assertions;
import static org.assertj.core.groups.Tuple.tuple;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

@Test
void ofComponent() throws Exception {
    MyFooObject myObject = MyFooObject.ofComponents(new Foo(1, "One"), new Foo(2, "Two"), new Foo(3, "Three"));

    Assertions.assertThat(myObject.getComponents())
              .extracting(Foo::getId, Foo::getName)
              .containsExactly(tuple(1, "One"),
                               tuple(2, "Two"),
                               tuple(3, "Three"));
}
```

Answer (score 5):

For excellent code-readability, [Fest Assertions](https://github.com/alexruiz/fest-assert-2.x/wiki) has nice support for [asserting lists](http://fest.easytesting.org/assert/apidocs/org/fest/assertions/Assertions.html#assertThat%28java.util.List%29)

So in this case, something like:

```
Assertions.assertThat(returnedComponents).containsExactly("One", "Two", "Three");
```

Or make the expected list to an array, but I prefer the above approach because it's more clear.

```
Assertions.assertThat(returnedComponents).containsExactly(argumentComponents.toArray());
```

Answer (score 1):

- My answer about whether `Iterables.elementsEqual` is best choice:

`Iterables.elementsEqual` is enough to compare 2 `List`s.

`Iterables.elementsEqual` is used in more general scenarios, It accepts more general types: `Iterable`. That is, you could even compare a `List` with a `Set`. (by iterate order, it is important)

Sure `ArrayList` and `LinkedList` define equals pretty good, you could call equals directly. While when you use a not well defined List, `Iterables.elementsEqual` is the best choice. One thing should be noticed: `Iterables.elementsEqual` does not accept `null`

- To convert List to array: `Iterables.toArray` is easer.
- For unit test, I recommend add **empty list** to your test case.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the solutions make sense and I agree with them. But for me, I would use `assertEquals` but I would sort the two lists.

```
assertEquals(sortedExpectedList, sortedActualList);
```

It is simple and the output still gives you the diff between the actual and the expected.